# Encrypted DNS without Tor Browser Bundle

Tags: configuration, anonymity, security, network-configuration

If using Tor and NOT Tor Browser Bundle, do you need to encrypt your dns or is setting your DNS on router to Cloudflare DNS sufficient?

- wanting to obfuscate all DNS from view of ISP

Comment: Are you talking about DNS for a tor client or tor exit relay?

Comment: i’m asking if if DNS needs to be encrypted if you are using the Tor client and not with the hardened Tor Browser. Example: using Tor and configure a browser like Chromium to use Tor, wouldn’t DNS queries be unencrypted and seen by ISP. Essentially i’d like to use Tor system-wide and be able to use anything from browser to terminal to use Tor AND have the DNS queries encrypted. Is an application like DNScrypt needed / need additional configuration?

Comment: Tor's SOCKS proxy will resolve DNS queries safely as long as your applications don't try to do DNS themselves. If your applications do try to perform DNS/hostname lookups, then yes you will leak your DNS queries. You can try to set up encrypted DNS which might hide your DNS from your ISP, but encrypted DNS is not private and your DNS provider (for example Cloudflare) will still be able to link you to the websites you visit.

Comment: How could I prevent all applications outgoing traffic besides specifically port 9050, which I believe is what Tor uses? This would result in all Torified traffic and DNS. Iptables or privoxy?

Comment: I don't see how privoxy would help here, but yes you probably want to set up firewall rules, or use some kind of network isolation like network namespaces. Make sure to block both tcp and udp, as well as IPv4 and IPv6.

Comment: Block everything? Wouldn’t I have to leave 9050 open?

Comment: Block everything except from the tor process. Port 9050 is a localhost port so that port isn't important here. Also relays can use any port numbers they want, so you can't leave specific ports open. Instead you should block all packets that don't come from the tor process itself.

Comment: How can I block everything that’s not routing through the Tor process?